getting java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name sun.security.util.Resources, locale en_US building parquet file, graalvm
while generating the parquet file i am getting below error, using spring boot native image with graalvm, below is the stack trace do i need to add resouce
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetWriter$Builder.build(ParquetWriter.java:566)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.util.HadoopOutputFile.fromPath(HadoopOutputFile.java:58)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:187)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:247)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:124)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:263)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1455)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$Key.<init>(FileSystem.java:1554)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:503)
at java.base@17.0.9/javax.security.auth.Subject.getSubject(Subject.java:306)
at java.base@17.0.9/sun.security.util.ResourcesMgr.getString(ResourcesMgr.java:40)
at java.base@17.0.9/sun.security.util.ResourcesMgr.getBundle(ResourcesMgr.java:54)
at java.base@17.0.9/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1708)
at java.base@17.0.9/java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:858)
at java.base@17.0.9/java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1549)
at java.base@17.0.9/java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1575)
at java.base@17.0.9/java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1683)
at java.base@17.0.9/java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:2045)
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name sun.security.util.Resources, locale en_US

i have tried with adding ressouces with runtime hints but still gettting the same error
hints.resources().registerPattern("core-default.xml");
hints.resources().registerPattern("core-site.xml");

